# Installing Ubuntu from USB stick gives error: "Operating system not found"

Tags: lubuntu, inspiron

I am trying to install Ubuntu from a USB disk on my Dell Inspiron 7537, but I get the error message: `Operating system not found`.

I have tried to disable UEFI and use Legacy but without success.

Comment: Switching to a different USB solved it for me.

Comment: Also solved it by switching to a different USB. My 64GB one didn't work, but my cheap 4GB one worked.

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer:**

1. use pendrive, not USB hard disk
2. format it as FAT32
3. plug the pendrive first, then power the computer on
4. enter BIOS before booting

**Detailed answer:**

Prepare USB stick exactly as described in Ubuntu documentation:

[How to create a bootable USB stick on Windows](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows)

[How to create a bootable USB stick on Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu)

This documentation refers to USB stick (a pendrive), I am not sure whether it is possible to boot from external hard disk connected via USB. If you are trying to boot from USB hard disk, it may be a reason of failure; try simple pendrive instead. Also note, that Ubuntu installer will fail when pendrive is formatted as NTFS, use FAT32 instead.

Plug the pendrive with Ubuntu installer into USB socket, then power your computer on. Press F12 to enter the Boot Menu and choose USB. If USB is not listed then simply enter the BIOS (position *Setup* in the Boot Menu), then exit and press F12 again; USB should be listed now.

After choosing USB from Boot Menu, Ubuntu installer should start.

Answer (score 1):

Hoping that you don't have any data on your HDD. If there is any data try to do back-up and follow these instructions:

1. Check for errors & Format both USB stick and Hard disk.
2. Load Ubuntu again on USB using any better tool like LiLi ([LinuxLiveUSB](http://www.linuxliveusb.com)).
3. Install Ubuntu.
4. Comment.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried many ways to solve this and finally when I used the following settings in BIOS, it booted successfully.

Devices-Configure SATA as "IDE"; Boot Mode: Legacy; Quick Boot: Disabled

Then I reinstalled Ubuntu from a usb and restarted the desktop.

I'm working on ThinkVision. And I'm not sure whether it's these settings make the difference, but it may worthy a try.